# Advice for Java HashMap alternative in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, hashmap

I have a database with this kind of a table, has more than 10 million rows.

```
ID  colA    colB    Length
1   seq1    seq11   1   
2   seq1    seq11   11  
3   seq3    seq33   21  
4   seq3    seq33   14
```

I want to loop though colA first, get the relevant colB value, and check if there are any other occurrences of the same value. 
For example in colB (seq11) there are 2 occurrences of colA(seq1), this time I have to combine those and output the sum of the length. Similar to this:

```
ID  colA  colB   Length
1   seq1  seq11  12
2   seq3  seq33  35
```

I am a bit Java guy, but because my colleague has written everything in PHP and this will be just an adding, I need a PHP solution.
With Java I would have used hashmap, so that I would have the colA data once and just increment the value of "Length Column".

---

I tried this query in order to group by occurences:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) SeqName FROM SeqTable GROUP BY SeqName HAVING COUNT(*)>0;
```

Comment: What kind of DB? SQL? If so, there's no point doing that in PHP. Use a `GROUP BY` clause with `SUM`.

Comment: hi netcoder, yes it is mysql db. i used group by but i could not integrate sum with it..

Comment: this can be done with SQL, try to update your question with a query that may work and if there's a problem we can help you to solve it!

Comment: @Naryl.. i mentioned the mysql query..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you can use an array like an hash map

```
$array = Array();
$array['seq1'] = Array();
$array['seq1']['seq11'] = 0;
$array['seq1']['seq11']++;
```

Or you can use an SQL query like this one:

```
select id,colA,colB,sum(Length) as Length from {tableName} group by colA,colB order by colA, colB;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is something easily achieved within SQL rather than in programming logic:

```
SELECT colA, colB, SUM(Length) as `length_sum`
FROM SeqTable
GROUP BY colA, colB
```

Of course you would still need PHP to iterate through the result set and do whatever it is you want to do with the data.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Mike Brant.. It seems that i was not aware that this can be achieved with SQL..